# Strange Python subrprocess.check_output behaviour

Tags: python, subprocess

I have the following Python code:

```
import visa 
import os
import subprocess
#import Enum


def enum(**named_values):
   return type('Enum', (), named_values)

InstrumentSelect = enum(RS_Spectrum_Analyser = 'Spectrum', Oscilloscope = 'Oscilloscope')


outp = subprocess.check_output(['C:\Temp\RsSpecExample.exe',InstrumentSelect.RS_Spectrum_Analyser])
print outp
outp = subprocess.check_output(['C:\Temp\RsSpecExample.exe', ])
print outp
```

When I run it the first time it works very well and I get the correct return value from the simple C# application in the .exe.

The second time I try to run the script I get the following behaviour:

```
 File "C:/Users/eoco/PycharmProjects/untitled/main", line 49, in <module>
outp = subprocess.check_output(['C:\Temp\RsSpecExample.exe',InstrumentSelect.RS_Spectrum_Analyser])
 File "C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.4\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
 File "C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.4\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__errread, errwrite)
 File "C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.4\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

When I check the folder in the C: drive, the exe is now gone and I no longer seem to have write access to the folder.

Any ideas?

Comment: is you exe still in its place after the first run?

Comment: Yes it is, it's only after the second run that it disappears

Comment: you've got 2 calls to the exe can you maybe add a check for a file after each one of them? to see at which point it vanishes?